# HOw to make an If condition as a certain action

Tags: jquery, if-statement

mm I'm a jQuery beginner. I wonder if it is possible to make an action as a condition of *if* in jquery. For example I want to put the condition as a hover for a certain div .. is that possible ?

Comment: can you show your code what u had done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need an if statement : just use classes or ID like that :

```
$('div.specDiv').hover(function(){
  // do what you want.
});
```

It means : find all the div with the class 'specDiv', and do specific thing on hover. **You just have to apply the classes on the element which need the action on hover**.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9MaA/). You can wait for a certain event and when it's fired do something, eg. hover, click etc.

```
$('.sample').hover(function() { // if element is hovered
    // logic
    alert('hovered');
});
```